# First & Last days of the month with time stamp macros

Tags: sql, datetime, sas, sas-macro

I have a SAS program I want to automate to run.  I have to pull the first date & the last date of the month with the time stamps.

This is what it looks like hard coded - that does work!  But I don't want to change it every month.

```
    %let st_dt= '2020-10-01-00.00.00';
    %let ed_dt= '2020-10-31-23.59.59';

    PROC SQL;
    SELECT t1.ENTRYTIME
    FROM MYTABLE t1
    WHERE t1.ENTRYTIME BETWEEN &st_dt. AND &ed_dt.
```

I have tried so many different things but cannot seem to get it to work. And BONUS, I'm pulling from transactional tables that have over 17 BILLION - yes BILLION WITH A B records.  I've tried using datepart on the ENTRYTIME & casting as a date - but with that many records it just runs forever and eventually gets killed - or just flat out fails!   :(

This is what I've tried so far - neither PROC SQL work.

```
    %let start=%sysfunc(intnx(month, %sysfunc(today()),-1), date9.);    
    %let end=%sysfunc(intnx(month, %sysfunc(today()),-1,e), date9.);

    PROC SQL;
    SELECT t1.ENTRYTIME
    FROM MYTABLE t1
    WHERE cast(t1.ENTRYTIME as date) BETWEEN &start. AND &end.
    
    PROC SQL;
    SELECT t1.ENTRYTIME
    FROM MYTABLE t1
    WHERE cast(t1.ENTRYTIME as date) BETWEEN &start. AND &end.
```

So if you can get me a macro or a let statement or anything that is formatted like this to automatically update without human intervention: '2020-10-01-00.00.00' & '2020-10-31-23.59.59' - BRING IT ON!   Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Do your variables have datetime values or strings?  Your first set of code is trying to  compare the variable values to string constants.  Your second set of code is trying to compare the variable values to variables with names like `01OCT2020`, but that is an invalid name for a variable since you cannot name variables starting with a digit.

Answer (score 0):

Just tack on the time suffix as constant text.

```
%let st_dt= "%sysfunc(intnx(month,%sysfunc(today()),-1,b),yymmddd10.)-00.00.00";
%let ed_dt= "%sysfunc(intnx(month,%sysfunc(today()),-1,e),yymmddd10.)-23.59.59";
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to pass through to ensure best performance.  The core syntax in the pass through is

```
entrytime >= 'yyyymmdd' and entrytime < 'yyyymmdd'
              ^^^^^^^^                   ^^^^^^^^
              1st of month               2nd of month

or

entrytime >= 'yyyymmdd' and entrytime < 'yyyymmdd'
              ^^^^^^^^                   ^^^^^^^^
              last of month              1st of next month
```

Example:

```
%let today = %sysfunc(date());

%let month_first_dt = %sysfunc(intnx(MONTH,&today,0));
%let month_last_dt  = %sysfunc(intnx(MONTH,&today,0,E));

%let month_first      = %sysfunc(intnx(DAY,&month_first_dt,0),yymmddn8.);
%let month_first_next = %sysfunc(intnx(DAY,&month_first_dt,1),yymmddn8.);

%let month_last       = %sysfunc(intnx(DAY,&month_last_dt,0),yymmddn8.);
%let month_last_next  = %sysfunc(intnx(DAY,&month_last_dt,1),yymmddn8.);

%let ss_MF_literal = %sysfunc(quote(&month_first,%str(%')));
%let ss_MFN_literal = %sysfunc(quote(&month_first_next,%str(%')));

%let ss_ML_literal = %sysfunc(quote(&month_last,%str(%')));
%let ss_MLN_literal = %sysfunc(quote(&month_last_next,%str(%')));

libname remote sqlsrv 'connection string';

proc sql;
  create table sas_table as select * from connection to remote
  (
    select entrytime from remote-table-name
    where
      entrytime >= &ss_MF_literal and entrytime < &ss_MFN_literal
      or
      entrytime >= &ss_ML_literal and entrytime < &ss_MLN_literal
  )
;
```

Comment: I keep forgetting to reply Richard.... THIS WORKED!!!  You rock & THANK YOU SO MUCH for the assistance!